# .val() retrieves default value, not typed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Inside of `$(document).ready()` is an `.on('click')` event handler. It binds to an empty div, we'll call it parentContainer.

The click handler looks like:

```
$('#parentContainer').on('click', #buttonthatWILLexisteventually, (function() { doStuff(); }));
```

The problem is, the objects I want to ultimately work with **don't exist yet**. I have another function that uses the .appendTo() jQuery function to insert input text fields, buttons (including #buttonthatWILLexisteventually) and other things into the #parentContainer.

What I would like #buttonthatWILLexisteventually (henceforth #btwee) to do is read the **current** value of the text field that was appended with it, when the button is clicked.

It works in jsfiddle when I do away with all the $(document).ready and inserting HTML nonsense and just stick to static HTML.

```
<div class="parentContainer">
        <h2>Server Log</h2>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="Filter" id="logfilter" value="Filter Log by [id]" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="logdebug" />
            <label for="logdebug">Display Debug Messages</label>
            <button class="changeNestedSetting" id="logclear">Clear</button>
            <button class="changeNestedSetting" id="logview">View Log</button>
        </div>
        <div id="iframediv"></div>
    </div>





  (function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.parentContainer').on('click', '#logview',(function(){
            console.log($("#logfilter").val());
            $('<div width="100%" height="600" id="logiframe"></div>').appendTo('div#iframediv');
            var logurlparam =  { filterlog: $("#logfilter").val() };
            var logurl = "echo/html?ID=" + logurlparam["filterlog"];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: logurl,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (html) {
                    $('<pre>' + html + '</pre>').appendTo('div.log');
                    $('div#logiframe').contents().find('body').append('<pre>' + html + '</pre>');
                }
            });
        }));
    });
    }());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3dV/15/

Unfortunately, the real-world example seems to create a catch-22; binding the click handler to the parent seems to imply that when I create the button inside of that parent, the click handler binds but I lose the ability to dynamically read the content of the text field; the value is always the default value (see: http://jsfiddle.net/k5rD2/1/). On the other hand, trying to do the click event in the same code as that which creates the internal content means that it doesn't bind.

Most other threads I've seen on this have recommended using .keyup() or .keypress() to "guess" the contents that were entered; this seems to be a terrible solution to a fairly straightforward problem, but as yet I haven't found anything better.

**Update:** had a JavaScript programmer go through my code with me tonight to see what I'm doing wrong. I managed to stump him; the only thing we could come up with was maybe jquery-ui (which is being used elsewhere on the page) has something to do with it?

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me after a few tweaks: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3dV/25/

Comment: `(function () { $(document).ready(function () {` ? want to add any more of the same thing?

Comment: that's the boilerplate I was working within...once I have this feature working I plan to refactor... :)

Comment: working in jsfiddle, not in my Eclipse project, but it seems there are some problems with my jetty server...will go troubleshoot those, and then come back to this. :P

Thanks @Blender

Comment: okay, so I updated jQuery, made sure jetty was all shiny, and had a JavaScript programmer go through my code with me tonight to see what I'm doing wrong. I managed to stump him; the only thing we could come up with was maybe jquery-ui (which is being used elsewhere on the page) has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code *was* working...in the div of the same name in the contents of the invisible tab, which was prior to the one I was working on in the DOM.

Fixing how I was using tabs in jquery-ui made the problem disappear.